# Spark-Streaming-Kafka: rebalancing partitions after having used Assign to seek latest offset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, offset, rebalancing

I have three Spark Streaming jobs that use `ConsumerStrategies.Assign[]()` to seek the latest offset that was committed into a database.

Each one of these jobs is reading from one of three partitions in a topic (for example: partition 0,1 and 2). If one of the Spark Streaming jobs fails, is it possible to rebalance that partition to one of the other two jobs that are currently running.

I know you can do that in normal Kafka using `ConsumerRebalanceListener`, `onPartitionsProvoked()` and `onPartitionsAssigned()`. But how would you do that in Spark-Streaming-Kafka?